# How does arm-eabi-gcc make sure that ".text" section in crtbegin_dynamic.o goes first in the final dynamically linked executable?

Tags: android, gcc, linker, arm, embedded-linux

From readelf we know that the entry point of an ELF executable file is "`_start`" in Android(32bit ARM), and "`_start`" is defined in ***crtbegin_dynamic.S*** for dynamically linked executables.

Question is: How does the build system make sure that the "`.text`" section in ***crtbegin_dynamic.o*** goes first in the finally executable image(so that "`_start`" goes first in "`.text`" section in the final executable image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is decided by linker (`ld`) which might implicitly called when you produce an executable with `gcc`.

First you should check ld's documentation on [Entry Point](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Entry-Point.html).

> The first instruction to execute in a program is called the entry point.
>
> ...
>
> There are several ways to set the entry point. The linker will set the entry point by trying each of the following methods in order, and stopping when one of them succeeds:
>
> - the `-e' entry command-line option;
> - the ENTRY(symbol) command in a linker script;
> - the value of a target specific symbol, if it is defined; For many targets this is **start**, ...
> - the address of the first byte of the `.text' section, if present;
> - The address 0.

You can try to play with -e option of linker via `-Wl,-eXXX`

```
$ echo "int main(void) {return 42;}" | gcc -Wl,-efoo -xc - -o t42
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol foo; defaulting to 00000000004003d0
$ readelf -a t42|grep 4003d0
59: 00000000004003d0     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter if `_start` happens first or last or in the middle of `.text`. The linker uses the `e_entry` in the [ELF header](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch4.eheader.html) to specify its actual address after linking.

However, the `crtbegin_dynamic.o` still must be the first, and `crtend.o` must be last, because they define the start and end of the constructors/destructors arrays, and the CRT/dynamic linker relies on that. The `gcc` or `g++` compiler driver ensures that by placing these objects at their corresponding places in the object file list when invoking the linker. You can see the full commandline by passing `-v` to `gcc/g++`.